# How to obtain PHP variable array values?

Tags: php, html

Here i am asking the user to enter in candidates names from the amount of textboxes they have specified in the page before this one. In my second page **Ballot.php** I am trying to write what was entered in these created text boxes to a text file but the called variable is always empty. Any ideas? Thanks

The values contained in $_POST["raceList"] and $_POST["canList"] are entered in values.

```
<form action="CreateBallot.php" method="post">
How many races within ballot?
<input type="number" name="raceList" id="raceList">
        <br>
        How many candidates in each race?
        <input type="number" name="canList" id="canList">
        <br>
```

**Page 1(CreateBallot.php):**

```
<form action="Ballot.php" method="post">
      <?php   

               for($x = 1; $x <= $_POST["raceList"]; $x++){

               echo ("<h1>Race #" . $x . "</h1><br>");
               echo ("Please fill in candidates:<br>");
              for($y = 1; $y <= $_POST['canList']; $y++){
                  $textboxes = array("<input type='text' name='txtbox' id='txtbox' value=''>");
                    echo $textboxes[0];
              }
               }


         ?>
<p><a class="btn btn-info"  href="Election Commissioner.php"  role="button" >Go Back &raquo;</a>
<a class="btn btn-info" id="startRace" href="Ballot.php" name="startRace" role="button" onclick="butclik();">Finish Ballot &raquo;</a></p>
</form>
```

**Page2(Ballot.php)**

```
Candidates:<br>
          <?php 
            $race1 = fopen("race1.txt" , "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
                $name1 = $_POST[$textboxes[0]];
                fwrite($race1,$name1 . "\r\n");

            fclose($race1);

        ?>
```

Comment: 2 words => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You are doing it all wrong..! What are the values contained in `$_POST$_POST["raceList"]` & `$_POST['canList']` ???

Comment: @Yes turn your `error_reporting()` on,Seems like you should be getting alot errors and you reported none..!

Comment: @Travis Whitten : How do you even submit the form cuz I tried the form wasn't even submitting at all without submit button ???

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai i added in the buttons to show you, i just left them off for shorter code purposes. The problem isn't error within my syntax. I get no errors at all.

Comment: @TravisWhitten : You still added the wrong code.As those are hyperlinks : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: @TravisWhitten : And you are just jumping to that link mentioned in your hyperlink `<a href="" >HyperLink</a>`,You are not posting any values at all from your form and also a hyperlink can't be used in normal circumstances for to do the job of a submit button.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is clean code of how you should be doing it :

**Note :** Assuming the `$_POST["raceList"]` & `$_POST["canList"]` to be containing positive integer values so Here is the code..!

**1st Page :**

```
<form action="2nd_page.php" method="post">
<?php   
for($x = 1; $x <= $_POST["raceList"]; $x++){
echo "<h1>Race #" . $x . "</h1><br>";
echo ("Please fill in candidates:<br>");
for($y = 1; $y <= $_POST['canList']; $y++){
echo "<input type='text' name='candidate[]'>";
}
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value"Submit Values">
</form>
```

**2nd Page (2nd_page.php) :**

```
<?php
$candidates = $_POST['candidate'];
for($i=0;$i<count($candidates);$i++)
{
$race1 = fopen("race1.txt" , "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$name1 = $candidates[$i];
fwrite($race1,$name1 . "\r\n");
fclose($race1);
}
?>
```

**Note :** There were alot of errors in your code..I fixed the errors also and it's working now.Just take a look at the code and observe what changed and how you are gonna do it next time.

**It's good to not repeat the same mistakes again..!**

Comment: Awesome, i figured out what i was doing!! Thanks so much!

Comment: @TravisWhitten : No Problem..! Don't hesitate in asking for more help if you need at all but make sure that you ask question in proper way with proper needed code so that we won't need to ask again again for the things which people mostly leave during the posting time..!